# Problema para copiar carpeta

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de que, al seleccionar una **imagen** desde la **galería**, esta se copie en alguna **carpeta aparte**. El problema es que no estoy pudiendo conseguirlo y no entiendo porqué. La idea es que, al presionar un `CardView` este abra la galería y al seleccionar la imagen, esta se copie en una carpeta aparte que se debe crear de manera programática. He intentado varias cosas pero no he dado con ninguna solución posible. Actualmente, estoy haciendo esto:

Clase **CopiarArchivos**:

```
public class CopiarArchivos {
    private static final String TAG = "logcat";
    private CopiarArchivos(String origen_fuente, String destino_archivo) {
        try{

            File inFile = new File(origen_fuente);
            File outFile = new File(destino_archivo);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int c;
            while( (c = in.read(buffer) ) != -1){
                out.write(buffer, 0, c);
            }
            out.flush();
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No se pudo copiar, error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        if(args.length == 2)
            new CopiarArchivos(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

En el Manifest tengo declarado los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

En el `MainActivity` lo primero que hago, es ejecutar el método que pide los permisos desde el `onCreate`:

```
private void EjecutarPermisos() {
    permissionHelper = new PermissionHelper(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
    permissionHelper.request(new PermissionHelper.PermissionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Log.d("TAG", "onPermissionGranted() called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIndividualPermissionGranted(@NotNull String[] grantedPermission) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onIndividualPermissionGranted() called with: grantedPermission = [" + TextUtils.join(",", grantedPermission) + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied() {
            Log.d("TAG", "onPermissionDenied() called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDeniedBySystem() {
            Log.d("TAG", "onPermissionDeniedBySystem() called");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (permissionHelper != null) {
        permissionHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

////onCreate
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EjecutarPermisos();
```

Ahora, desde el `onCreate` controlo el `Listener` del `CardView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EjecutarPermisos();
    //código extra
    NavigationView n_V = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View headerView = n_V.getHeaderView(0);
    final CardView c_v_prueba = headerView.findViewById(R.id.c_v_prueba);
    try {
        c_v_prueba.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    Intent abrir_galeria = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    abrir_galeria.setType("image/*");
                    abrir_galeria = Intent.createChooser(abrir_galeria, "Elige una imagen");
                    startActivityForResult(abrir_galeria, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        );
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.d("CARD_VIEW", "cambiar_imagen: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
```

Con eso consigo abrir la **galería** y se me muestran las **imágenes**, ahora desde el `onActivityResult` controlo la selección del **archivo** y el **copiado** del mismo hacia otra **carpeta**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri mUri = data.getData();
        File imageFile = new File(ObtenerRutaDesdeUri(mUri));
        String mRutaImagenSeleccionada = imageFile.getPath();
        CopiarImagen(mRutaImagenSeleccionada);
    }
}
```

Los métodos que utilizo para **copiar, extraer, y renombrar** el archivo son los siguientes:

```
public void CopiarImagen(String rutaImagenSeleccionada) {
    String nombreImagen = NombreImagen(rutaImagenSeleccionada);
    String nombreDirectorio = "Fotos de perfil";
    String rutaDirectorio = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            + BARRA
            + nombreDirectorio;

    File fileDirectorio = new File(rutaDirectorio);
    String rutaFinalImagen = rutaDirectorio + BARRA + nombreImagen;
    String[] args = {rutaImagenSeleccionada, rutaFinalImagen};

    if (!fileDirectorio.exists() || !fileDirectorio.isDirectory()) {
        CrearDirectorio(nombreDirectorio);
    }
    CopiarArchivos.main(args);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Imagen copiada en: " + rutaDirectorio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public String ObtenerRutaDesdeUri(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    int indice_columna;
    String ruta = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            indice_columna = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            ruta = cursor.getString(indice_columna);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "ObtenerRutaDesdeUri ha generado el siguiente error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return ruta;
}

private String NombreImagen(String rutaImagenSeleccionada){
    String prefijo = "IMG_";
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String extension = String.format(".%s", ObtenerExtensionArchivo(rutaImagenSeleccionada));
    return String.format("%s%s%s",prefijo,timeStamp,extension);
}

public static String ObtenerExtensionArchivo(String fileName) {
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
}

public File CrearDirectorio(String nombreDirectorio) {
    File directorio = null;
    try{
        directorio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), nombreDirectorio);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "CrearDirectorio error: No se creo el directorio público. " + e.getMessage());
    }
    if(!directorio.mkdirs()){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: No se creo el directorio público");
    }
    return directorio;
}
```

Pero, en el `LogCat` me figuran los siguientes errores:

```
2021-06-06 18:05:38.732 14129-14129/com.frabasoft.mitaller E/logcat: Error: No se creo el directorio público
2021-06-06 18:05:38.733 14129-14129/com.frabasoft.mitaller E/logcat: No se pudo copiar, error: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210606_150003.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Pero, desde la aplicación tengo el permiso aceptado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podría decir, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? O, ¿Qué parte del código es el que está mal diseñado? Desde ya, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que una solución a este problema podria ser lo siguiente:

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- Este atributo es "false" por defecto en apps targeting Android Q. -->
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 ...
</application>
```

Si quieres entender más sobre esto mírate [Casos practicos y prácticas recomendadas de almacenamiento en Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases)

Comment: Pues no, no ha funcionado.